# Passing .. operator to array

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

Can I define `..` as named array in list pattern without additional slices?

Something like

```
string s[] = {"<=","some","text","=>"}

if (s is ["<=",..{Length: >1} AS string[] subarray, "=>"])
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join('\n', subarray));
else 
  Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
```

Comment: yukky syntax usage sorrily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is something like the [compiling and functioning](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LY24Ib),

This code uses a C# 11 [list pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#list-patterns) to assert the first and last values  of a sequence and captures the slice pattern `..`, for the 0 to many items in between to a new variable. Then a [property pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#property-pattern), checks the `Length` of the captured array, finally assigning the capture to `subString`.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] s = new[] {
            "<=",
            "some",
            "text",
            "=>"
        };
        
        if(s is ["<=",  .. string[] {Length: > 0} subString, "=>"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join('\n', subString));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I assumed this solution, but I thought it is possible to do that somehow using list patterns from c# 11.

Comment: @Reverin, I defined a list pattern, using the slice pattern (`..`);